# Eclipse plugin: about the function --println(String) in org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsoleStream

Tags: eclipse-plugin, console, println, large-data

Recently I am doing  a eclipse plugin project with eclipse_RCP. But I encountered some issues with eclipse UI when I wanted to print a large number of messages in the console of plugin.

The messages are  from  a complex process which could be considered as a  factory producing messages  all the time and never stop (until the client stop the process of course).

**When I printed the message before (the message is short), I just needed to call the function -org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsoleStream.println().**

BUT this time ,when I tried  like before at first , the runtime-EclipseApplication (launch the debug mode)  **stopped responding** and then tell me  **out of memory**.

It seems like that the eclipse will read all the messages in the memory and THEN print them to the console one time .So when the number of message is large ,it will out of memory.

My issue is **what can I do if I  want to print the message line by line in the console ?**

My description may be not accurate. Below is the java code:

```
    public  void print(Process p) {     
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()),1024);
    String line = "";

    try {   
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //it is correct when print in the main console
                System.out.println(line);   
                //when print in plugin console .it is out of memory
                //this is the function
               //org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsoleStream.println()
                 println(line);

        }
        in.close();
        this.flush();
        this.close();
        p.destroy();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {     
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then I try to write to a file at first and let the MessageConsoleStream read from the file every 1000 messages,but it looks like the same .

```
        public  void print(Process p) {     

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()),1024);
    String line = "";
    char []tem = new char[1024];
    int i = 0  ;
    try {   
        File temp = File.createTempFile("temp", ".tep",new File("E:/"));
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(temp);
        MessageConsoleStream mcs = null;
        while((line = in.readLine())!=null){

            if(i<=1000){
                System.out.println(line);
                out.write(line+"\n", 0, line.length()+1);
                i++;
            }
            else{
                i=0 ;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                FileReader fr=new FileReader(temp);
                mcs = CConsole.getMessageStream("consoleName", "file name");
                while( fr.read(tem, 0, 1024)!=-1){
                    mcs.print(String.valueOf(tem));
                    }
                mcs.flush();
                mcs.close();
                fr.close();
                out = new FileWriter(temp,false);                   
                }   
        }
        if(i!= 0){
            mcs = CConsole.getMessageStream("consoleName", "file name");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            FileReader fr=new FileReader(temp);
            while( fr.read(tem, 0, 1024)!=-1){
                mcs.print(String.valueOf(tem));
                }
          mcs.flush();
            mcs.close();
        }
        in.close();
        p.destroy();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {     
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

All the ways above will make the eclipse out of memory when the number of messages more than 600,000 (then I  stop the process ,otherwise it will out of memory).

It looks like the ecplipse  wants to print all of them  one time but not line by line.So it reads and reads again until out of memory.

BTW,I find a note in the org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsoleMessage.java——

> Clients should avoid writing large amounts of output to this stream
>   in the UI  thread. The console needs to process the output in the UI
>   thread and if the client  hogs the UI thread writing output to the
>   console, the console will not be able  to process the output.

That is not the real reason ,isn't it ?

I also notice that both the cdt and jdt are ok when printing a large number of message .How did they do  ?

THANKS！

Comment: Eclipse for RCP & RAP Developers , version is Eclipse Platform 3.7.1 and EPP RCP/RAP Feature 1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `flush()` method every so often to write the `MessageConsoleStream` out to the console.

The `flush()` method is part of the `IOConsoleOutputStream` class, in the `org.eclipse.ui.console` package.  The `flush()` method is not well documented, so I can see how you might have missed it.

Comment: But  even I use the flush() method every time when I call println(String str) method , the eclipse  stop  responding either.

Comment: thanks for your reply :)
I have tried to new a MessageConsoleStream , but it seems useless.